# Custom script for git blame from vim

Tags: vim

I want a minimum way of using git blame from vim (I don't want to use the whole Fugitive plugin). What I have right now is this:

This function is from the vim help page and enables me to open shell commands in a scratch buffer.

```
function! s:ExecuteInShell(command)
  let command = join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))
  let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . command . '$')
  silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'botright new ' . fnameescape(command) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
  setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap number
  echo 'Execute ' . command . '...'
  silent! execute 'silent %!'. command
  silent! execute 'resize ' . line('$')
  silent! redraw
  silent! execute 'au BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr('#') . ') . ''wincmd w'''
  silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . command . ''')<CR>'
  echo 'Shell command ' . command . ' executed.'
endfunction
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:ExecuteInShell(<q-args>)
```

Together with the above function I would like to do:

```
noremap <leader>b :Shell git blame -L line(".") - 5, line(".") + 5 %<cr>
```

to get a git blame window for the rows around the cursor position in the current buffer.

Now I have two questions:

1: How can I make the scratch buffer that opens read-only so I can close it using only q? I would like to make this change in the function so that all: Shell commands can be closed with q.

2: How can i get line(".") - 5 expand into current line - 5 row number?

Comment: I know you already said you don't want to use [fugititive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), but it has to be said, "fugitive.vim may very well be the best Git wrapper of all time". There is are some nice [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes on the fugitive: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/). `:Gblame` is a wonderful way to explore the history of a file: [Every line of code is always documented](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2014/02/hidden-documentation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a buffer read-only and not modifiable, you can put

```
setlocal readonly nomodifiable
```

at the end of your function.

In the case of your next question, you can use `execute` and `eval`

```
noremap <leader>b :execute "Shell git blame -L " . eval(line(".")-5)) . ",+10 %"<cr>
```

I recommend to read these descriptions, and `help` in general:

- [`:h execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute)
- [`:h eval`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#eval%28%29)
- [`:h readonly`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27readonly%27)
- [`:h nomodifiable`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27modifiable%27)

---

Also here is the [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window) to the mentioned function on [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com).

Comment: Might also point out that I am wrong that readonly allowes me to quit a buffer using only q. Not sure what is is that allowes me this feature... Any sugestions?

Comment: What do you mean by using only q? If you mean `:q`, it works for me. If you want to quit buffer with just pressing the key `q` in normal mode, I would advise you against it. `q` is used for recording a macro (more info e.g. [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros))

Comment: Some windows for example neerdtree tagbar etc can be closed using only q not :q. I like that functionallity for theese buffers but not sure how to enable it on my custom buffer.

Comment: O.k., put this line `nnoremap <buffer> q :q<CR>` inside your function, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I use a simple hack to get my vim git integration:
This solves my git commit/add , blame and op.

```
map <F5>  :!git add %;git commit -m "commit" %<CR>
map <F3> :!git blame % > %.blame<CR>:vsplit %.blame<CR>
map <F4> :!git log --abbrev-commit % > %.log<CR>:vsplit %.log<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have something here, the script can be copied and added to the .vimrc file.

- command Blame will run git blame on the current file, will split the screen and put the result of 'git blame -w' into the lower buffer (buffer is put into read only mode), your cursor will be in the blame buffer (current line as in source file)
- while in the lower buffer: GShow will split the lower screen and open the commit 'git show -w [hash]' for the current line in the right hand buffer (buffer again in read only mode).

```
"======================================================
" Function runs git blame on file in current buffer and 
" puts output into a new window
" move to current line in git output
" (can't edit output)
"======================================================
command! -nargs=* Blame call s:GitBlame()

function! s:GitBlame()
   let cmdline = "git blame -w " . bufname("%")
   let nline = line(".") + 1
   botright new
   setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
   execute "$read !" . cmdline
   setlocal nomodifiable
   execute "normal " . nline . "gg"
   execute "set filetype=cpp"
endfunction

"======================================================
" function runs git show on report of git blame;
" the first token of a line is taken as SHA checsum of the 
" git commit
"======================================================
command! -nargs=* GShow call s:GitShowFromBlame()

function! s:GitShowFromBlame()
   let curline = getline( "." )
   let tokens = split(curline)
   let cmdline = "git show  -w " . tokens[0]
   "botright new
   "topleft new
   "vsplit new
   "vnew new
   vertical new
   setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
   execute "$read !" . cmdline
   setlocal nomodifiable
   execute "normal 1gg"
   execute "set filetype=cpp"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on this

```
fun! GbSyncLines(is_ow2bw)
  let l:ow = getbufvar(+expand('<abuf>'), 'origWindow')
  let l:bw = getbufvar(+expand('<abuf>'), 'blameWindow')
  let l:origLine=line('.', win_getid(l:ow))
  let l:blameLine=line('.', win_getid(l:bw))
  if a:is_ow2bw == 1
    eval win_execute(win_getid(l:bw), "windo call cursor(" . l:origLine . ", 0)")
  else
    eval win_execute(win_getid(l:ow), "windo call cursor(" . l:blameLine . ", 0)")
  endif
endfun
fun! GbMake(view, origWindow)
    let l:origWindow=a:origWindow
    let l:file_dir=expand('#'.winbufnr(a:origWindow).':h')
    let l:file_name=expand('#'.winbufnr(a:origWindow).':t')
    let l:origLine=line('.', win_getid(a:origWindow))

    sil exe a:view
    setl buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe
    exe "lcd ".l:file_dir
    exe "0r ! git blame " . l:file_name
    setl nomodifiable
    setl nonumber norelativenumber
    if v:shell_error != 0
      exe l:origWindow . "wincmd w"
      return
    end
    eval searchpos('(')
    eval searchpairpos('(', '', ')')
    norm! gE
    exe "vertical resize " . col('.')

    let l:blameWindow = winnr()
    let b:blameWindow = winnr()
    let b:origWindow = a:origWindow

    let l:origLine=line('.', win_getid(b:origWindow))
    eval cursor(l:origLine , 1)

    nnoremap <buffer> <C-]> :call GcommitShow(expand("<cword>"), line(".")) <CR>
    au BufWipeout <buffer> call win_execute(win_getid(getbufvar(+expand('<abuf>'), 'origWindow')), "windo setl scrollbind&")
    au WinEnter <buffer> :call GbSyncLines(1)
    au WinLeave <buffer> :call GbSyncLines(0)

    setl scrollbind
    exe a:origWindow . "wincmd w"
    setl scrollbind
    exe "syncbind"
    if a:view == "enew"
      exe l:blameWindow . "wincmd w"
    end
endfun
fun! GcommitShowClose()
    let l:w=getbufvar(expand('<abuf>'), 'origWindow')
    let l:l=getbufvar(expand('<abuf>'), 'origLine')
    let l:v=getbufvar(expand('<abuf>'), 'origView')
    eval GbMake("enew", l:w)
    eval winrestview(l:v)
    eval cursor(l:l, 1)
endfun
fun! GcommitShow(commit, linenr)
    let l:origWindow=b:origWindow
    let l:viewsave=winsaveview()
    sil exe "enew  | setlocal buftype=nofile | setlocal bufhidden=wipe | 0r ! git show " . a:commit
    setl nomodifiable
    setl nonumber norelativenumber
    if v:shell_error != 0
      eval GbMake('enew', l:origWindow)
      return
    end
    let b:origWindow=l:origWindow
    let b:origLine=a:linenr
    let b:origView=l:viewsave
    nnoremap <buffer> <C-O> :call GcommitShowClose()<CR>
    eval cursor(1, 1)
endfun
fun! Gb()
   eval GbMake('vnew', winnr())
endfun

command! Gb call Gb()
```

while in the blame window, CTRL+] shortcut will show git show for commit the cursor is on. Then CTRL+O will get back to the git blame.
Note lcd on start - command will work even when you are not in the git dir. The [gist](https://gist.github.com/vboykox/472711bf328c7f1c8d102dc98079f061)